# Swift - Table View - Repeat order of different sections for multiple data

Tags: swift, uitableview, asynchronous, custom-cell

I have a table with four different sections. After I fetch data from the database and store them in an array, I want to display them in the table view. This means, for each object, I will extract information and put it into the correct section of the table view.

To describe it more simple:
Object 1

TableViewCell 1
TableViewCell 2
TableViewCell 3
TableViewCell 4

Object 2
TableViewCell 1
TableViewCell 2 ..

Currently, my approach looks like

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
 UITableViewCell {
 let participationObject = Participation(json: (hitsSource?.hit(atIndex: indexPath.row))!)
    checkIfUserAlreadyRatedForParticipationContent(participationObject: participationObject)
    
    if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section % 4 == 0) {
        let userProfileCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "userProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! ChallengeInfoUserTableViewCell
                     
        self.dataAccessService.fetchUserById(completionHandler: { (challengeOrganizer) in
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ChallengeInfoUserTableViewCell
            userProfileCell.fullNameLabel.text = challengeOrganizer.firstName + " " + challengeOrganizer.lastName
            userProfileCell.fetchProfileImageOfUser(userObject: challengeOrganizer)
            userProfileCell.fetchNumberOfWonChallengesByOrganizerId(challengeOrganizer: challengeOrganizer)
            
            userProfileCell.starNumberLabel.text = challengeOrganizer.stars
            userProfileCell.delegate = self
        }, uid: participationObject.userId)

        return userProfileCell
    }
           
    else if (indexPath.section % 4 == 1) {
        let challengeImageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "challengeImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ChallengeInfoImageTableViewCell
        
        dataAccessService.fetchParticipationImageByParticipantIdChallengeId(completionHandler: { (participationImage) in
            let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ChallengeInfoImageTableViewCell
            challengeImageCell.checkIfToAddOrRemovePlayIcon(participationObject: participationObject)
            challengeImageCell.setChallengeImage(challengeImage: participationImage)
            challengeImageCell.delegate = self
            challengeImageCell.moreButton.tag = indexPath.row
        }, participantId: participationObject.userId, challengeId: challengeObject.id)

        return challengeImageCell
    }
           
    else if (indexPath.section % 4 == 2) {
        let commentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "commentCell", for: indexPath) as! ChallengeContentDetailCommentTableViewCell
        commentCell.fetchCommentsByParticipationId(participationObject: participationObject)
        return commentCell
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}
      
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return (hitsSource?.numberOfHits())! * 4
}
```

I have two issues:
1.) I get always the same object from my data source
2.) When calling **let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ChallengeInfoImageTableViewCell** It crashes at some point.

Is my approach even legit? Is it clean?

Answer (score 0):

1. This depends on the data array and you are ignoring the `section` parameter in `numberOfSections(in:)`
2. **Never** retrieve data asynchronously in `cellForRow` and update the cell by calling `tableView.cellForRow(at:`. Cells can be moved off screen immediately so there is no `cellForRow(at`.

Note:

The first expression in `(indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section % 4 == 0)` is redundant. `indexPath.section % 4` is 0 if `section` is 0.

Comment: Hello @vadian. Thanks for the reply. I didn't understand how and why I should use the section parameter? And also, my data array contains different objects but I only get the first one. What do you mean with it depends on my data array?

Regarding the second point. Should I move the async loading into the  ChallengeInfoImageTableViewCell class itself?

Comment: You get only the first one because you return (fixed) 1 in `numberOfRowsInSection`. Asynchronous tasks are supposed to be executed in the **controller** or the **model**, but not  in the **view**

Comment: How can I modify the code above so it fits my expectation? I provided 1 as a fixed value but no matter which value I provide, it is displayed wrong.

Comment: You have to **refactor** your code. Create a suitable data model, populate it  - the `Participation` stuff and the depending network tasks - in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear` and in `cellForRow` just update the UI.